# Transformation of Linked list from Raw pointers to Smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

How can I implement my linked list code from raw pointers to smart pointers. Any guidelines will be helpful. Here is my [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3864ae7c4058ebf6).

Actually I'm more confused about the type of smart pointer. Shared or unique and what will be the head. And how I gonna delete this whole list in destructor?

```
#include <iostream>

class List{

private:

struct Node{
 int datum;
 Node* next;

 Node(int d, Node* n):datum(d),next(n){std::cout<<"Constructor: "<<datum<<"\n";}
 ~Node(){std::cout<<"Destructor: "<<datum<<"\n";}

};
Node* head=nullptr;

public:

~List() {
        while (head) {
            Node *temp = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }

void append(int d){
    Node* t = getLastNode(head);
    (t ? t->next : head) = new Node(d, nullptr);

    }

  Node *getLastNode(Node *n) const {
        for (Node *it = n; it; it = it->next)
            if (!it->next)
                return it;
        return nullptr;
    }    


};


int main(){

List l1;
l1.append(1);
l1.append(2);    


}
```

Comment: Well, what did you try (links don't count)? `std::unique_ptr` seems to be more appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Can you please give me an example? I don't have good concepts of smart pointers.